# Amplify.Auth.SignOut() problem with Apple login, while the Amplify.Auth.SignIn() works fine

Tags: flutter, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

When I call Amplify.Auth.SignOut(), it opens safari, but the address seems to be invalid, and it can't be reached and the user can't be logged out. This only occurs when using Apple login as a sign in method, for every other instance seems to be working just fine. What is weird to me that sign in works just fine, it opens the browser and the prompt for apple id, but the logout is the problem. Did anyone have a similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to my info.plist file fixed the issue.

```
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
     <array>
      <dict>
       <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
         <string>NAMEOFYOURAPP</string>
        </array>
       </dict>
      </array>
```